# What should be the field type for Managed range filter to work in Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa

I have a field **Price** of type **Number**. I want to filter search result based on minimum and maximum price entered by the user. The search result variant contains the field Price. Now when i click on filter after entering the Min and Max values, the result count is 0.

The hash formed is

```
https://sitename/?sc_itemid=%7B2E9F8666-3979-49F3-BAEF-457AF1BD08CD%7D&sc_mode=preview&sc_lang=en&sc_site=Site#inventory-search_price%20facet=400|3000
```

I am i missing anything ?

Comment: What version of SXA are you using? Check your facet item and ensure that the `Field Name` field contains the proper field name. Just for a test, you can also remove all spaces and dashes form your facet name and check it then (I recall a bug with spaces in facet names some time ago - that is why I asked you about SXA version).

Comment: SXA version is 1.8. the field name is rent (have added the same in index file too) and Facet name is PriceRange, earlier there was a space i have removed it now. Still the results are not getting filtered